# Is there a way to check for ellipsis on text using nightwatch?

Tags: nightwatch.js, nightwatch

Is there a way to check for ellipsis on text or text that has been truncated using nightwatch. I tried to use `browser.assert.ok(ref.offsetWidth < ref.scrollWidth)` but it seems like Nightwatch does not have attributes offsetWidth nor scrollWidth. Has anyone encounter this before ?

Answer (score 1):

NightwatchJS by itself might not support this.

As far as I know, there is a possibility to do this using Javascript.

I remember doing something similar but don't have any code or example.